# What is the meaning, history, and current popularity of "of a Monday" (or Tuesday, or Wednesday, etc.)?

Tags: phrases, british-english, history, expressions

I was watching a 1934 Hollywood film today and one of the American characters used the phrase, *Of a Tuesday*. I don't think I'd ever heard an American use this in real life or in a film before then, even though I watch a lot of 1930s and 1940s Hollywood movies. I have since heard it used occasionally in films from about the 1920s to the 1960s, but I have still never heard it used outside of films.

Perhaps this, like the MidAtlantic accent in the first half of the century, was and is something used by actors, and in this case writers, far more commonly than by regular (non-theatrical) Americans.

Does phrase *Of a Tuesday* simply mean the same as *On a Tuesday*? Is it a commonly used phrase? Has the meaning or popularity changed significantly over time? Are there differences in meaning or usage between British and American English?

So, what are the meaning(s) and usage(s), history, and current popularity of both in American and British English?

Comment: Please could you give examples of sentences that make use of *X-Day* and *Y-Day* that allow me to understand them. I have not heard them used ever. The only reference I have found is in Wikipedia, relating to military jargon.

Comment: @MattЭллен See http://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USA/DAP-Poland/Campaign-Chron.html 14 Jul to 1 Sep.

Comment: @Kris - Thanks, although that still seems to be military jargon, rather than something someone would use in everyday speech. I'm at a loss as to what Sarah is asking about *of a Y-Day* and *of an X-Day*.

Comment: I think we're talking about sentences like, for example, "I enjoy walking in the park *of a Sunday*".  Right? If so the question could be made a bit clearer and more concise but it's an interesting question.

Comment: @z7sgѪ Oh! That actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Matt and Kris Sorry for the confusion! The mixing of X and Y to represent the day-of-the-week variable happened because I realized later that X would need _an_, whereas any day of the week would use the article _a_, then forgot to change the title of the question.

Comment: @z7sgѪ Ѫ That's it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Barrie England's answer is very good but doesn't address the American English part of the question. Is it a good idea to accept this answer anyway, community standards-wise?

Comment: You ask if it is in American use. I, too, thought it was exclusively British - but I have been listening to some Vic and Sade broadcasts of 1938-40 - and find it often used there.

Answer (score 9):

If your question is about the use of *of* before a day of the week, then the answer is that, at least in some varieties of British English, it is used to mean ‘at some time during, in the course of, on’. This use has its origins in Old English and has been in continuous use for 1500 years. Here are just three examples from the Oxford English Dictionary:

> Always of a Monday morning he was on the dock a good half-hour before
>   the expected arrival of the boat for town.
>
> Mr. More . . . expounds the universe and the Platonical soul to 'em in
>   St. Clement's Church of a Monday afternoon.
>
> Kippers of a Friday, roast of a Sunday.

Comment: Yes. Great examples. So, was this at any time used to the exclusion of _on a Monday_? or _on Monday_? While the _of_construction sounds lovelier to me, poetic even, _on_ makes more sense. I'm sure it's mostly because it's what I'm used to, but then in the case of _on_ vs. _in_, which I ask about [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54251/in-an-american-street-but-on-a-british-one-does-the-twain-ever-meet), while _in_ sounds wrong, I can better understand the sense of it than the _of_ in _of a Sunday_. Also, any info on American English usage of this?

Comment: @sarah: The OED’s note on this usage says ‘Apparently taking the place of the Germanic and Old English genitive of time. Now only implying regularity or repetition.’ It’s also found in expressions such as ‘I like to have a beer or two of an evening.’ I doubt, however, if it was ever used to the total exclusion of anything else and I don’t think we can any longer consider it as being Standard English.

Comment: +1 : for the etymology - it would be interesting to know if an equivalent survived in German.

Comment: @cindi: You mean the genitive of time? Yes, it survives in German expressions such as 'eines Tages' - one day.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I was really wondering if there was a parallel construction in German (or other cousin language) to "I have a lie-in of a Sunday"

Comment: @cindi: I’m not really qualified to say. German has the preposition ‘auf’, but I don’t know its etymology and the translation of ‘of’, where it’s needed, is usually ‘von’. However, there is an expression ‘Die Nacht auf Dienstag’, literally ‘the night on (but possibly of) Tuesday’, which means ‘Monday night’. We need a German language specialist to tell us more.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I see. So, along with _of a weekday_ and _of an evening_, I'm guessing _of an afternoon_ and _of a morning_. Any others? _of an October_? _Of a decade_? Haha. Probably not. When you say no longer standard English, that surprises me, as I've heard it frequently enough from Brits.

Comment: @Sarah : I +1ed the answer not the comment

Comment: @sarah: Yes, there are other possibilities, but 'of a decade' is not among them. By ‘Standard English’ I meant that variety of the language that is, in one linguist’s words, ‘(1) written in published work, (2) spoken in situations where published writing is most influential, especially in education (and especially at University level), (3) spoken “natively” (at home) by people who are most influenced by published writing - the “professional class” ’. I don’t think you’d find the ‘of a’ construction in such places.

Comment: I would only add that it's currently standard in Appalachia, less commonly with the day of the week, but quite commonly with the time of day.  "I like to sit here of an evening."

Comment: @ Barrie I couldn't believe my ears! Last night, on (American TV show) Saturday Night Live, a skit had the Mitt Romney character say, "the fact is, the whole family and I love to watch sporting events on television of a weekend." The skit was emphasizing his awkwardness, stiffness, and rich-guyness (financially upper classness.)

Comment: @sarah: That would be a normal way of expressing it in BrEng.

Comment: @BarrieEngland if you will address current usage in your answer I think I would select it.

Comment: All I can say is that it is very informal. I wouldn't expect to find it in, for example, academic prose.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I edited the question trying to clarify what I'm trying to find out. Maybe it needs further editing. I don't understand what "genitive of time" is, but I do get the "implying regularity or repetition." So, is the OED saying "of a Sunday" is now _only_ used to apply to a thing done regularly or often on Sunday? Also, how can I find out about the meaning and popularity of this phrase in American English?

Answer (score 5):

I hadn't thought that construction particularly BrE. Do you mean [Way out West (1937)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96po3FRJ9uk) ? *He died of a Tuesday* is a very ancient Musical Hall joke in which case Stan Laurel is the missing link. If not, what is the film - maybe it had an English writer.

I think the accent (Katharine Hepburn is the worst offender) is usually referred to as Mid-Atlantic - I also found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Theater_Standard

Comment: Thanks. That clip shows that the audience would have been expected (or at least hoped) to be familiar with the _of a weekday_ phrase. Also, thanks for _Mid-Atlantic_ accent. Weird because I'm a native to the Mid-Atlantic US states, and we don't talk at all like that. I see it was also called _Transatlantic_, which I prefer!

Comment: I'm not positive it belongs here on english.se--maybe linguistics.se would be better, but there are similar questions here, so I've posted a question slightly expanded from this idea [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54249/did-regular-americans-speak-they-way-actors-in-the-30s-and-1940s-did.) Maybe you'd be interested in posting an expanded answer.

Comment: Good thought to check, though it turns out the writers were all Americans. Interestingly, one,  [W. E. Woodward](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0941003/bio#trivia), _was credited with creating a new down to earth style of biographical writing and for coining the word "debunk"._ The film was [Evelyn Prentice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025091//).