# ON an American street, but IN a British one. Do the twain ever meet?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english, in-on

In the United States, we say that someone lives ***on*** a street, whereas I've noticed that British people say ***in***. For instance:

> Bubba lives **on** Washington Street.
>   Colin lives **in** Cavendish Avenue.

I believe we both would use ***at*** when a number is given. For instance:

> Bubba lives **at** 16 Washington Street.
>   Colin lives **at** 7 Cavendish Avenue.

I don't think it matters if it's a road, avenue, street, circle, or lane — as far as I know, in America, we always live ***on*** a street. Does it vary in British English, or is it always ***in***? If it varies, what are the rules?

Comment: *In the street* and *in the road* are the normal terms in BrEng, but we say ‘The word on the street is that . . .’

Comment: I remember that when I first heard the song by Madness, I thought "our house, in the middle of our street" was literally in the middle of the street, i.e. where the cars ought to go. I think this is part of why "lives in [street name]" just sounds totally wrong to me.

Comment: No. There is an ocean in the way.

Comment: To be fair, I would prefer not to live in or on the street. Shall we say "along"?

Comment: @Marthaª If "lives in [street name] just sounds totally wrong," could "lives **on** [street name]" sound more acceptable? Some people on this earth literally do live **on** certain streets.

Comment: @Kris, I don't understand what you're asking. Naturally, ***on*** *[street name]* sounds acceptable to me: that's the American way to say it, and is what this question is asking about. --??

Answer (score 15):

One thing to keep in mind is that for a long time, people lived "in" Cavendish. Note that there may have been a couple roads in Cavendish, none of which had names, but you were speaking of a geographical entity rather than a linear place. Even as recently as 1998, when I lived in Kathmandu, you could be in "Thamel" or Jawalakel (two neighborhoods), but on any one of about 6 streets.

Americans, having lived less long in ancient place areas view roads more as routes rather than locales, hence the differentiation - Americans live on a route between two places, whereas Britons live in a place, that has taken on a road name.

Comment: An interesting suggestion.

Comment: Americans live *in* towns, same as the English. They just don't live *in* **roads**, because that would wreak havoc with traffic. So, interesting suggestion, but I don't think it holds any water. Unless you have cites to support it?

Comment: Right - and the point is that the evolution of road names has more of a place feel in ancient times / places. The citation of Kathmandu is an example here. Interestingly, as the roads were named, they took the place names, and people would still say "I live in Thamel Street"

Comment: Good thought. And of course some people live literally *in* a cathedral close, for example.

Comment: Ah, that explains how Paul McCartney wrote "Why Don't We Do It IN the Road"!

Comment: I always imagined Paul doing this http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/commercial/2011/6/17/1308266116195/Vancouver-riot-kiss-coupl-001.jpg

Answer (score 6):

As commonly happens in this age of global communication/mass media, British usage is shifting more in line with American. Until a couple of decades ago, British usage favoured [in the high street](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20high%20street,in%20the%20high%20street&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) by a factor of about four to one...

[image]

...but if that chart is to be believed, it's nearer 50-50 today. Though per comments below (special thanks to @sarah), I wouldn't want to overstate the recent trend implied by the chart. Although the corresponding AmEng usage chart shows a marked preference for *"on"*, it does show a significant number of instances for *"in"* - almost all of which turn out to be spurious, in that the sources are invariably British, but misclassified. It's also worth noting that *"high street"* is quite rare in AmEng anyway, which in itself suggests many such instances may be wrongly classified.

Comment: In BrEng, ‘in the high street’ seems to be used to indicate a location (‘The post office is in the high street’) and ‘on the high street’, to indicate something less tangible (‘Business on the high street took a turn for the worse last year’).

Comment: Which would accord with my suspicion that US usage may be influenced by the fact that on average their streets are physically *longer*, and more likely to be accessed by vehicle rather than on foot. Thus "on" has a general tendency to be less geographically specific.

Comment: As far as I know, Americans don't use the term *high street*. I suspect that people who use *high street* are very likely to be British, even if they aren't classified so by Google books or are writing in America. Compare the [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+main+street%2Cin+the+main+street%2C+on+the+high+street%2C+in+the+high+street&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=5&smoothing=3) for *in the main street/on the main street,* which is the closest I can come to American for *high street.*

Comment: What Peter said.

Comment: @Peter Shor: You're right - the "frequency" value in my Ngram shows "high street" is 8 times more common in the UK than US. My substantive point, also shown by your Ngram, is that US usage has increasingly favoured "on" in all contexts over the past century. And that, particularly over the past couple of decades, the UK is following suit. In short, the answer to OP's question *"will ever the twain meet?"* is that it's already happened/happening.

Comment: After cursory examination of the context of the instances represented, I think we need to be careful with what we think we're learning from these Ngrams. For instance, [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20high%20street%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2003,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en) is the page linked to the 2003 to 2005 instances of _in the high street_ in American English from the Ngram FumbleFingers posted to support the notion that _in the high street_ is somewhat popular in AmEng. Looks like every source on that page is British. More later...

Comment: Also, we have _in the High Street painting_, as an example of AmEng usage, which, clearly, is not relevant to our discussion.

Comment: @PeterShor Absolutely true. And, I'm pretty sure that even _the main street_ in AmEng does not translate to what _the high street_ means in BritEng. For one thing, we can talk about the _main_ street that meets various criteria (the street mainly used for X, the most important street for X), but not so for the _high_ street (the street highly used for X?, the most altitudinous street for X?) Not to say this invalidates FumbleFinger's main point.

Comment: @sarah: I have no idea what [in the High Street painting](http://bluecedaronline.co.uk/category.php?id_category=35) would be relevant to. That link, the one and only reference currently indexed by Google, is an "obituary" reference to one *Paul the Artist, a Glastonbury resident who sadly died on 1st March 2011.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Here's the relevant part of the sentence: _Paul was often seen in the High Street painting the local shops and scenes..._. So, not relevant to the question. Did you check on my other point--the references listed as AmEng are from Brit sources. Am I seeing that correctly?

Comment: @sarah: You do indeed seem to be seeing things correctly! I couldn't possibly check every AmEng instance in detail, but I just leafed through several pages. In every case where the "country of origin" was obvious, it was actually British! Things are probably skewed by the fact that *"the high street"* itself is relatively rare in AmEng, but clearly Google Books classification of US/UK is far from perfect. I think my substantive point (BrEng is moving towards the AmEng style on this one) remains true, but the idea that AmEng preference isn't overwhelming does now look like utter tosh! I'll edit

Answer (score 4):

Having lived for many years in both Britain and the USA, I've noticed that Americans often drop the designation that follows the proper name of the street, whereas British people rarely do.

So an American is quite liable to say either

> I live **on** Cavendish

or

> I live **on** Cavendish Street,

whereas a British person is much more likely to say

> I live **in** Cavendish Street

Comment: Perhaps dropping the designation (Street, Road, Avenue, Close, Way, etc.) is likely to be more ambiguous in Britain: (1) there may be, say, both a 'Road' & an 'Avenue' or 'Close' with the same 'proper name', so dropping the designation would be ambiguous; (2) the 'proper name' may be the name of a place to which the road leads, e.g. 'Worthing Road' in Horsham is the road leading to Worthing, which is 20+ miles away, so saying "I live in Worthing Road" & "I live in Worthing" have completely different meanings.

Comment: To amplify my previous comment: In the village I live in, we have *Lyons Road* & *Lyons Close*; *Park Road*, *Park Street*, & *Park Street Lane*; a house called *Pinkhurst* & a road/track called *Pinkhurst Lane*.  We formerly had *Hayes Road* & *Hayes Lane* (now all just *Hayes Lane*), as well as various property names beginning *Hayes ...*. Occasionally, a road name may be abbreviated where it is not ambiguous, or by common local usage, but generally, because road names often include other place names and/or are named after pre-existing farms, properties, etc. omission can be ambiguous.

Comment: @TrevorD: there are lots of places in the U.S. where you have *Streets, Roads, Avenues* with the same name (not *Closes*, though). For example, 32nd Street and 32nd Place are a block away from each other near where I grew up in Washington D.C.

Comment: @PeterShor I wasn't aware of that - but I'm not disputing it either. My comment related to the part of the Answer that stated "Americans often drop the designation that follows the proper name of the street, whereas British people rarely do."; and I was offering a possible explanation for that.

Answer (score 3):

"On" sounds completely American to me.  Though like many American expressions it is familiar here, (especially since Freddy Eynsford-Hill was made to sing "On the street where you live" in *My Fair Lady*). But I think most Brits would normally "in".

Comment: As a Brit I agree. But I think there's a slight 'size/importance' consideration though. For example, the Natural History Museum is on (rather than in) Cromwell Road because it's so big. So maybe Americans live in bigger houses than us Brits :)

Comment: @tinyd: you may be right, but I'm not convinced. The NHM is just as much "in" as "on" Cromwell Road for me. An ngram for "In/on Oxford Street" shows an overwhelming prevalence of "in" over "on" in both US and UK English, but "on" has been increasing: in the US since 1880, to the same level as "in", and in the UK since 1960, reaching half the prevalance of "in".

Comment: that's interesting. I suppose purely from a physical point of view you could make a case that a building that takes up an entire block could be thought of more as 'on' whereas a house that's nestled in amongst other houses is more likely to be 'in'. But I'm not convinced of my own reasoning here...

Comment: @tinyd: Personally, I've no real preference for either preposition, but Google Books says 9,900 hits for ["in Cromwell Road"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22in+Cromwell+Road%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), as against only 2,240 for ["on Cromwell Road"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22on+Cromwell+Road%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). But you may be right about "size matters" - that's 4:1 for a big road, but with the much smaller Chancery Lane it's more like 150:1 in favour of **in**.

Answer (score 3):

I actually live *in* a road called "The Street".
A small town I previously lived in also had a road called "The Street".

"The Street" is a not-uncommon street name in some parts of the UK, particularly in villages, but also in some towns. It arises from the time when that was the *only* road in the community, and hence it didn't need a distinguishing name.

So, I might say to a local person "I live *in* The Street".

I certainly would not say "I live *on* the street", because that may imply that I am homeless and am *literally* living *on the street*.

[Thanks to @tchrist for confirming that the expression "living on the street" to refer to a homeless person is not restricted to BrE usage.]

Comment: That isn’t a specifically British expression.  It’s universal in English anywhere.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks - I didn't know & didn't want to assume. But I was also distinguishing between "*in* and *on* the street" in BrE for reasons apparent from my expanded answer.

Comment: @TrevorD Interesting case, that. So, a letter addressed to you would have something like 234 The Street on the envelope? I lived om Street Road once. Local lore was that it was originally *Straight Road*, but the spelling was inexplicably altered over time.  This reference http://courses.wcupa.edu/jones/his480/notes/z-trans.htm says 1683 William Penn laid out Street Road (PA926) in a straight line to connect a number of Quaker communities.

Comment: @sarah No, no house numbers. Address is '[House name], The Street, [Village name], Postcode (Zipcode)]. I believe our village name is unique worldwide! Our neighbour's house was built about 1650, and has been extended once - in about 1970! The original village church dated from mid-1100s, and after various extensions was replaced in 1890s. Our nearby main road beats yours by c.1500 years! It was originally built by the Romans (who occupied Britain c.43 - 410 AD) and it still follows the same dead straight route. About 1 mile away was the Roman equivalent of a 'Service Station'.

Comment: @TrevorD That's too cool! If you name the village, I can do an image search. I'm guessing it's near Hastings. (I'm a Foyle's War and Poirot fan, not least because of the fantastic locations used in the filmings.)(Then again, I suppose this is more than enough off topic talk...)