# On Paddington Station?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I was interested to read that [Paddington Bear](http://www.paddingtonbear.com/paddingtonsbiography.html) was found *on* Paddington Station, not *in* or *at* Paddington Station. I would never have chosen this usage (I speak Canadian English). I had a look at [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20Paddington%20Station,in%20Paddington%20Station,at%20Paddington%20Station&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and found that **at** is by far the more common usage, with **on** and **in** coming far behind and with comparable usage. I did a similar search for *on*, *in* and *at* [Euston Station](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20Euston%20Station,in%20Euston%20Station,at%20Euston%20Station&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) with similar results. Then I did the same search for [Grand Central Station](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20Grand%20Central%20Station,in%20Grand%20Central%20Station,at%20Grand%20Central%20Station&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which, unlike Paddington and Euston stations, is in New York. Here, **at** and **in** are neck-to-neck, with **on** coming a distant third.

I assume, therefore, that "on X station" is a mainly British English usage. I'm curious to know *why*. What is it that one is *on*? Is it the platform that we're on? Surely not the rails? Does anyone know where the use of these three prepositions comes from wrt train stations? How does usage in other English speaking countries compare? Writing as a Canadian, I would lean toward the Grand Central Station usage i.e. *at* or *in*, but not *on*. How about other places such as airports? We're not *on* [Heathrow](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20Heathrow,in%20Heathrow,at%20Heathrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), are we? Are we *on* the bus station?

Comment: In New York, they use **in** for **Penn Station**.

Comment: See also: [*ON an American street, but IN a British one. Do the twain ever meet?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54251/on-an-american-street-but-in-a-british-one-do-the-twain-ever-meet)

Comment: Technically it's Grand Central Terminal - trains can go no farther south. There is, however, a subway station just below or to the side that shares its name.

Comment: **On station**, or **on X station**, is an old Naval usage - it refers to being on patrol or blockade duty within a prescribed area of the sea (more recently, the same term is used in military aviation.)  I wonder whether Michael Bond (the author of the Paddington books) had that construction in mind?

Comment: @MetaEd thanks, that's an interesting discussion. Will the twain ever meet indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In/At the station is perfectly correct.
On the station is unusual but acceptable, because you would be *on* a platform in the same way that you would be a *on* a dock or *on* a quay.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say they used the Preposition "on" in the article because the Subject of the sentence is a bear stuffed toy, and "on" suggests the manner in which the toy was found literally on the surface of the platform.

Similarly, I suppose some people might also say "on Paddington station" in the same way that they would say "on the platform."

British English would also prescribe "**at** the station." And "**at/ in** Nottingham" for a place that's a point on a journey.

Comment: "stuffed toy" - how dare you sir! Paddington is very real