# Why do legal documents use "at" before names of cities?

Tags: grammar, legalese

I was looking at a proof of loss form, and below my signature there is a section for another affiant's signature which reads:

> Declared severally before me at  ______________________

From examples all over the web, affiants write only the name of the location (ex: “**Boston**” or “**Boston, MA**”).

Can someone please explain why how this is grammatically correct?

To me, it makes more sense for it to read “declared severally before me at **the city of Boston**”, or “declared severally before me **in Boston**”?

Comment: Related [Usage of 'at' and 'in' for cities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125983).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's acceptable legalese.  Legal writing uses many conventions not commonly used in day-to-day writing.  This same usage of *at* is applied in legal descriptions of real estate as well, often describing a property as being *at* a city or *at* a county rather than *in* it.  Legal jargon has evolved expressly for legal purposes, so *ex curia*, it is often not standard fare.  However, to be fair, such linguistic oddities are not exclusive to the field of law and its jargon.  It is quite usual for an industry or a field to have special words and grammar that is understood by its members and a few others in the know but not by lay persons.  Such is the nature of jargon: to create or bend language in order to widely meet specialized needs.

Comment: +1 With the law such non-standard uses often represent much earlier uses which have been retained because the need for "backward compatibiity" with prior forms and precedents is of critical importance.