# at/in city [when country follows city ]

Tags: prepositions

I know we generally use in for "city, town and country  ". But I am confused about when "the country " follows "the city". Which one should we use?

> 1) I live in Mumbai in India.
>
> 2) I live at Mumbai in India.

Comment: The country is merely a disambiguator; either *at* or *in* may be acceptable in some circumstances. See *[Usage of 'at' and 'in' for cities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125983)* and *[Correct usage of ‘on’, ‘at’ and ‘in’ from a foreigner’s point of view](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75)* among others.

Comment: I live in Mumbai, India.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Mumbai, India. no need to put other words between country and city.

Comment: I know that I can write this way. But I want to know what should I do in that case too.

Comment: I live in Mumbai of India.

Comment: That means both are wrong?

Comment: It's "in" Mumbai.  You could say "I live in Mumbai, which is in India"--one might do that with a small town where the listener or reader might not know the country.  Mumbai is well-known, though.

Comment: @Xanne What's the problem if I say number (1)?

Comment: It's grammatical, but not idiomatic.  Would it make sense for someone to say "I live in London in England"?  In Tokyo in Japan?

Comment: *Mumbai, India* is a predominantly AmE usage following their *Akron, Ohio* "City, State" format.  In BrE it would be *Mumbai in India*.

Comment: @Xanne I have seen a few grammar books to suggest number (2) in that case. But it totally sounds bad to me.

Comment: Then Mumbai in India is fine.

Answer (score 0):

'in' is a point in an area.
'at' is a point to another point.
e.g. I live in the city.
e.g. There is a well in the garden.
e.g. Mom is at home.
e.g. Mom is cooking in the kitchen.
e.g. I work at the airport.
e.g. There is a thief in this airport.

Answer (score -2):

as for me,i think,it should be "i live at mumbai in India" reason being that,Mumbai is in India,so "at" Mumbai ,and Mumbai is "in" India
in as much as we can take that short form but we can also take this other form