# in/on/at the seafront avenue

Tags: prepositions

I've read [the thread about the use of *in* and *on* with street names in BrE and AmE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54251/on-an-american-street-but-in-a-british-one-do-the-twain-ever-meet), but I'm still wondering what the preposition with "seafront avenue" might be. I did use *in*, but *at* sounds familiar too - probably because of the "seafront"?

Comment: Is “seafront avenue” a proper name?  Nobody that I know of uses seafront avenue in any general way.

Comment: It is the Thessaloniki seafront avenue in a book about Thessaloniki (Greece).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. All three prepositions are grammatical -- use of one or the other depends on the context and intended meaning. The noun ("seafront avenue") is a substantially large space, so it can take all of the prepositions. See the definitions and usage of the prepositions instead.

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Well there could be a bend in Thessaloniki seafront avenue. The restaurant could be on Thessaloniki seafront avenue. We could all meet at Thessaloniki seafront avenue and Main St.

Comment: "Farmers park their tractors **at** the seafront avenue of the northern Greek city of Thessaloniki. Greek farmers started a rally to protest against high taxes and their ..."; "The city has an incredible number of cafes, many of them right **on** the seafront avenue, "; "The hospitality project Carpe Diem Lounge Club for the Grupo Tragaluz is located **in** the seafront avenue of Barcelona with a big terrace just in ..." (src: Google Search). HTH.

Comment: Eastbourne has a "Seaside Road", which isn't very near the seafront.

Comment: It can be any of the three, depending on how you want to depict it.

Answer (score -1):

Oxford Collocations Dictionary has two examples:

- a house in Acacia Avenue
- an office building on Fifth Avenue

in an/the avenue (British English), on an/the avenue (especially North American English)

Comment: Hello, Ivan. The more general question you're answering here has already been asked and answered on ELU.