# worked on Wall Street vs worked in Wall Street?

Tags: prepositions

I was wondering whether it is worked on Wall Street or worked in Wall Street. I guess it is "on", I am not sure why.

Comment: Are you asking about British English or American English?

Comment: I depends on whether it is using "Wall Street" to mean the finance industry, or the office premises happen to be on Wall Street. In UK we still use "Fleet Street" to refer to the newspaper industry, but many of them have relocated.

Comment: I mean finance company located on wall street) American engish

Comment: You can find an answer here: [ON an American street, IN a British one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54251/on-an-american-street-but-in-a-british-one-do-the-twain-ever-meet). I'd add that "on" is pretty much universal in American English, where "in" would indicate being actually in the middle of the street. "In" is pretty general in British English, but you sometimes hear "on". For your sentence, in American English, it's "worked _on_ Wall Street".

Comment: Thanks a lot)))

Comment: @WeatherVane In BrE, "In Fleet Street" could mean having offices there **or** merely "in the newspaper industry"; we don't use *on,* and it's for the context to differentiate which is meant. Is it the same in AmE, with using "Wall Street" to mean the finance industry (in) as opposed to where offices are located (on)?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, to my knowledge, no one ever says " _in_ Wall Street" in US English for any reason, except to refer to "in the middle" of the street. If you work in finance, you work" _on_ Wall Street" (an expression that is indeed used to mean that someone works in finance).

Comment: In UK English "I work on Fleet Street" could be said by someone who worked in a coffee shop on that street.

Comment: Google Ngrams is interesting, 'in Wall Street' appears more common up until the 1970's, and 'on Wall Street' is now predominant.  Maybe the change coincides with a  physical dispersal of the financial industry from its traditional heartlands.

Answer (score 3):

Wall Street, in the context of this question, is a metonymn, like Hollywood, Broadway, The West End.  We are referring to the financial sector based in lower Manhattan.  "Worked in" is more appropriate when referring to metonyms, because you work in that particular industry but, unusually in the case of Wall Street, and Broadway "worked on" is a better fit.  Maybe because they are streets.  But then so is Whitehall, and politicians work in Whitehall, not on it.

Comment: It could just be that 'I' had a hot dog concession on Wall Street.

Comment: This answer describes what we say in NYC. I suppose that it's because Wall Street and Broadway are streets, and we usually do things "on" a street, not "in" it (unless you are actually physically standing in the street). Occasionally you hear "in Wall Street", but it's no more common than nonstandard use of a preposition in any other situation.