# Is the expression 'of an evening', 'of a morning', 'of a Saturday', good English or dialect?

Tags: dialects, non-standard

People will say: *He usually comes round here about 8 o'clock **of an evening**, or 10 o'clock **of a morning**, or **of a Saturday afternoon***.

Is this standard English? I tend to associate it with Londoners.

Comment: I think you are asking for this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54228/what-is-the-meaning-history-and-current-popularity-of-of-a-monday-or-tuesda

Comment: I grew up and still live in the American South (NE Georgia). "Old people" I grew up around often used this expression.

Comment: My Mom was from Abington, VA and used that expression when referring to a time of day: of a morning, of an afternoon, of an evening. I still use it, as does my brother. I'm 64.

Comment: I've heard it and used it myself here in Australia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ODO says that  ***[of an evening](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of)(or morning etc,)*** is an informal expression  meaning:

> - at some time in the evenings (or mornings etc.).

Examples:

> - If you're generally stuck for something to have ***for dinner of an evening,*** then hop along to The Red Kitchen and see what people there are having.
> - Besides, the three of you look impossibly cute when you're sat ***like that of an evening.***
> - Now - you MUST bring Connie over to the club ***for dinner of an evening soon***; my wife was only talking to her last week and she was saying it's been so long since we've all eaten together!

Or

> - on most evenings (or mornings etc.).

Examples:

> - When I was growing up The Archers was a regular feature, always on in the kitchen ***of an evening*** and my sister and I were forced to keep quiet for the critical 15 minutes.
> - Thanks for confirming my long-held belief that I'm better off slowly destroying my liver than staying in ***of an evening.***
> - We've come to delight in having a few tealights burning ***of an evening.***

From: The American Heritage ® Dictionary of the English Language:

> - “[Some speakers](https://www.englishforums.com/English/CorrectGrammar/gbwp/post.htm) of vernacular English varieties, particularly in isolated or mountainous regions of the southern United States, use phrases such as of a night or of an evening in place of Standard English at night or in the evening, as in We’d go hunting of an evening.”

(www.englishforums.com/English/CorrectGrammar)

Comment: Thanks Josh. I knew there must have been a previous post on this somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The expression "of an evening" and the like would have been standard usage in Old English - by which I mean the language as it was in the Anglo-Saxon era.  OE as you may know was a language which often used inflection of the noun without needing a preposition and in all of the MS I have seen the case form used for this expression is genitive - which in ME employs "of".  So in OE one would use "æfenes" the genitive case form of "æfen"

Comment: Very interesting answer.